# Shader gives wrong fragment color

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I've run into the strangest problem I've ever had in my shader experience. I created some test shader code (see below) and ran it on a simple texture.

Basically what I was trying to do is make my shader check the color of a fragment, and if it was within a certain range it would color that fragment according to a uniform color variable. The problem I'm having is that my shader does not correctly recognize the color of a fragment. I even went as far as to check if the red portion of the color is equal to one and it *always* returns true for every fragment. Yet if I use the same shader to draw the original texture it works just fine.

Why is this happening? The shader compiles without any errors what so ever. I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Code (if you have access to LibGDX you can run this code for yourself).

```
// Vertex
#version 330

in vec4 a_position;
in vec4 a_color;
in vec2 a_texCoord0;

out vec4 v_color;
out vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

```
// Fragment
#version 330

in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoord0;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    // This is always true for some reason...
    if(v_color.r == 1.0) {
        outColor = color;
    } else {
        // But if I run this code it draws the original texture just fine with the correct colors.
        outColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0);
    }
}
```

```
// Java code.
// Creating sprite, shader and sprite batch.
SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture("testTexture.png"));
ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("vertex.vert"),
                Gdx.files.internal("fragment.frag"));
// Check to see if the shader has logged any errors. Prints nothing.
System.out.println(shader.getLog());
// We start the rendering.
batch.begin();
// We begin the shader so we can load uniforms into it.
shader.begin();
// Set the uniform (works fine).
shader.setUniformf("color", Color.RED);
// We end the shader to tell it we've finished loading uniforms.
shader.end();
// We then tell our renderer to use this shader.
batch.setShader(shader);
// Then we draw our sprite.     
sprite.draw(batch);
// And finally we tell our renderer that we're finished drawing.
batch.end();

// Dispose to release resources.
shader.dispose();
batch.dispose();
sprite.getTexture().dispose();
```

The texture: [image: simple texture]

Comment: And what colors do your vertices have? If you can use the above code, then apparently they are white. So it's no surprise that the condition is true.

Comment: This is of course the logical reason, but I don't see how my vertices could be white when the only thing I'm rendering is this 32x32 texture?

Comment: You are passing a vertex attribute `a_color`. What data do you provide for this attribute in the vertex buffer? If you want to compare the texture color, you should of course sample the texture first.

Comment: ... I feel really stupid now. Thank you, and if you wish you can post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 input colors for your fragment shader: one sent as a vertex attribute and one as a texture. You intend to check the texture color but instead you check for the color value sent as the vertex attribute.

```
// Vertex
#version 330

in vec4 a_position;
in vec4 a_color;    // <--- A color value is passed as a vertex attribute
in vec2 a_texCoord0;

out vec4 v_color;
out vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;    // <--- you are sending it to fragment shader
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

---

```
// Fragment
#version 330

in vec4 v_color;    // <--- coming from vertex buffer
in vec2 v_texCoord0;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    // This is always true for some reason...
    if(v_color.r == 1.0) {   // <--- and then checking this vertex attribute color 
        outColor = color;    //      instead of what you send from texture
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```